# Command not found when trying to set up substrate

Tags: substrate

This is the first time I use the terminal on my mac OS. I have followed the instructions so far and restarted Terminal. I tried again making sure I followed every step. That is the reason it says it's already there. The next item I copied and pasted says command not found. Should I delete and start over?

```
-bash: rustup: command not found
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:~ el1748eth$  git clone -b v2.0.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
fatal: destination path 'substrate-node-template' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:~ el1748eth$ cd substrate-node-template/
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:substrate-node-template el1748eth$ cargo build
-bash: cargo: command not found
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:substrate-node-template el1748eth$
```

Comment: Please try running these commands: `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh` and `source ~/.cargo/env`

Comment: Do I wait for it to install before moving on to the next one? 1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
>

Comment: When I paste the next step it tells me.. info: aborting installation

Comment: Yes, you should wait for each step to complete before moving on to the next one. You may also want to join us in our technical chat where you can more easily share code and screenshots and stuff. https://app.element.io/#/room/!HzySYSaIhtyWrwiwEV:matrix.org